# &#65279 - Aparece esse erro entre o <body> , e dá diferença de espaço

Tags: html

Como faço para remover este erro? Está causando espaçamento no cabeçalho do site.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Achei uma solução bem interessante, chama-se boom o arquivo.
Este arquivo php você pode colocar na pasta raiz do seu site, ele é uma espécie de scan, que por sua vez, acessa todos os arquivos e ajusta os valores de BOM de cada arquivo.

```
<?php 
// Tell me the root folder path.
// You can also try this one
// $HOME = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
// Or this
// dirname(__FILE__)
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

$HOME = dirname(__FILE__);

// Is this a Windows host ? If it is, change this line to $WIN = 1;
$WIN = 0;

// That's all I need
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>UTF8 BOM FINDER and REMOVER</title>
<style>
body { font-size: 10px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background: #FFF; color: #000; }
.FOUND { color: #F30; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$BOMBED = array();
RecursiveFolder($HOME);
echo '<h2>These files had UTF8 BOM, but i cleaned them:</h2><p class="FOUND">';
foreach ($BOMBED as $utf) { echo $utf ."<br />\n"; }
echo '</p>';

// Recursive finder
function RecursiveFolder($sHOME) {
  global $BOMBED, $WIN;

  $win32 = ($WIN == 1) ? "\\" : "/";

  $folder = dir($sHOME);

  $foundfolders = array();
  while ($file = $folder->read()) {
    if($file != "." and $file != "..") {
      if(filetype($sHOME . $win32 . $file) == "dir"){
        $foundfolders[count($foundfolders)] = $sHOME . $win32 . $file;
      } else {
        $content = file_get_contents($sHOME . $win32 . $file);
        $BOM = SearchBOM($content);
        if ($BOM) {
          $BOMBED[count($BOMBED)] = $sHOME . $win32 . $file;

          // Remove first three chars from the file
          $content = substr($content,3);
          // Write to file 
          file_put_contents($sHOME . $win32 . $file, $content);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  $folder->close();

  if(count($foundfolders) > 0) {
    foreach ($foundfolders as $folder) {
      RecursiveFolder($folder, $win32);
    }
  }
}

// Searching for BOM in files
function SearchBOM($string) { 
    if(substr($string,0,3) == pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf)) return true;
    return false; 
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

O arquivo você pode colocar qualquernome.php, na raiz. Espero que possa ajudar a quem for necessário com este mísero e chato erro de bom.

Comment: Obrigado! mano.

Answer (score 6):

`&#65279` é um caráter especial do html, ou também, códigos do `ISO Latin-1`, que podem ser colocados no código-fonte como qualquer outro caráter alfanumérico, para produzir caracteres e símbolos que não poder ser gerados com comandos normais de teclado, são também conhecidos como `html_entities` numa breve abordagem.

---

**Leitura Recomendada:**

[Special Characters in HTML](https://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html)

[HTML Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Answer (score 5):

Este valor (65279 == 0xFEFF) provavelmente é um BOM (*byte-order mark*) que está no seu arquivo (HTML). Abra o arquivo em um editor binário e veja se esses bytes estão no arquivo. Por exemplo, no Visual Studio, selecione "File -> Open", e no diálogo "Open File", selecione a opção "Open With..."

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E selecione a opção "Binary Editor". Se você achar os bytes `FEFF` no arquivo, é só removê-los.

Comment: Abri pelo EditPlus, mas não achei...

Comment: Não conheço o EditPlus, mas alguns editores de "texto" escondem os BOM (o UltraEdit, que eu uso é um deles), mesmo no modo Hex Viewer...

Comment: Hmmm, mas eu até transformei o arquivo em bom + utf8, mas também não resolve o problema, tendo em vista que também há scripts em PHP

Comment: Entendi dorival, Mas não consegui mesmo achar uma solução, seu post talvez seria melhor esclarecer com qual programa eu poderia fazer isto, tendo em vista que não tenho esse que o Carlos citou... estou meio perdido ainda

Comment: É o VisualStudio Community? @carlosfigueira

Comment: Hmmm OK @DorivalZanetto - Vou testar sua solução pra ver... Mas eu já abri em vários editores e não consegui identificar onde está este código... :(

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30345/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-rafael-kendrik).

Comment: O VS Community tem essa opção também (eu estou usando o VS Professional).

Answer (score 5):

O Carácter em questão **&#65279** é o carácter *unicode* "*zero width no-break space*" (U+FEFF).

Pode ser que você copiou ele no seu codigo via *copy and paste* (CTRL + C e CTRL + V) sem perceber isso. O fato é que este não é visível se você está usando um editor de texto cujo o qual exibe carácteres *unicode* verdadeiros.

Uma opção é abrir o arquivo em um editor básico (por exemplo o editor de texto do windows) que não interprete *unicode* ou um que não interprete mas consiga exibir carácteres não ASCII.

Depois que você localizar o trecho de código, você pode excluir o bloco de texto em torno dele e o redigitar.

[Fonte: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html)]