# Erro em codificação de arquivo ou carácter

Tags: php, html, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8

Em todas as páginas de um site que estou desenvolvendo com codificação **UTF-8**, definida tanto no *charset* do `<head>` quanto na codificação do editor, estou tendo problema na renderização de palavras que possuem acentos, por exemplo:

A palavra *Médico* renderiza como *M�dico*.

Levando em consideração que estou testando em meu *localhost*, utilizo PHP e o problema persiste em todos os navegadores que testei, como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Poste o código da página com problema, mas pode ser na configuração do servidor ou mesmo do navegador.

Comment: Estou testando localhost. O problema é o mesmo com todos os navegadores. 

dentro do <head> uso: <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: PHP? Se for utilizar ``header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');``

Comment: PHP sim. Já uso como citado acima.

Comment: Provavelmente seu editor de código está em outra codificação, ou seu DB.

Comment: Não mencionou PHP na pergunta. Se estiver usando banco de dados, também é "relevante" mencionar. E essa questão sobre charset depende de muitos parâmetros. O problema pode ter N causas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu costumo fazer da seguinte forma:

- Em códigos PHP, use no topo da Index o código `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
- Em HTML, coloque `<meta charset="UTF-8">`
- No seu editor, recorte todo o conteúdo, mude a codificação do arquivo para (UTF-8 sem BOM) e depois cole o conteúdo novamente.
- Se estiver a usar PDO junto com MySQL, poderá usar esse parâmetro na construção de sua conexão: `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"`
- Pegue o costume de sempre criar arquivos UTF-8 sem BOM desde o começo - [Veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16556/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-arquivos-encodados-com-bom-e-sem-bom)

Isso deve resolver o seu problema em 99% dos casos.

Answer (score 2):

O problema pode estar relacionado tanto a codificação do arquivo quanto a algum erro no *output* do seu PHP.

Comece alterando/conferindo a codificação do arquivo abrindo-o em sua IDE, alterando a opção de *encoding* (ou codificação em português), para UTF-8. Abaixo estão os passo a passo de dois editores que acredito serem os mais utilizados por profissionais atuais no mercado e dev. iniciantes:

**caso utilize o *Sublime text*** você pode alterar indo em:

File -> reopen with enconding -> UTF-8 (inglês)

Arquivo -> reabrir com codificação -> UTF-8 (português)

**caso utilize o *Notepad*:**

Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8 (inglês)

Codificação -> Converter para UTF-8 (português)

Para demais IDE's você pode consultar a documentação da mesma.

Após feito o passo acima, verifique se em PHP, está utilizando exatamente `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`.

Verifique também utilizando uma ferramenta de *debug* (como por exemplo o *Dev Tools* do Google) se o *output* do seu código é exatamente esse: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`, sem qualquer carácter amais. Há algum tempo li um texto que dizia a respeito desse código que contem o *charset* necessitar obrigatoriamente estar entre os primeiros 512kb do documento para evitar alguns bugs em alguns *browsers*. Infelizmente não consegui achar o link para você dar uma olhada e também acredito que o problema relacionado a isso já deve estar resolvido, porém, apenas para garantia recomento que coloque entre a 1º e 3º linha do seu arquivo, eu costumo o colocar logo apos o `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">` esse estando na primeira linha apos abertura do `<head>`.

Bem, se após tudo isso o seu problema persistir, ele pode também ser um BOM (*byte-order mark*) estando relacionado ao ASCII, ocasionado normalmente por cópias por *copy and paste* conhecido também como CTRL + V e CTRL + C, falei sobre isso [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92639/65279-aparece-esse-erro-entre-o-body-e-d%C3%A1-diferen%C3%A7a-de-espa%C3%A7o/92643#92643). Simplificando, para resolver você pode abrir o arquivo em um editor básico (por exemplo o editor de texto do windows) que não interprete *unicode* ou um que interprete mas consiga exibir carácteres não ASCII e apagar o trecho de código com problema redigitando o mesmo.

Por ultimo, pode estar relacionado também a conexão *MySQL*, caso utilize, segundo [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361459/php-pdo-charset-set-names) do usuário *Jpsy* no SO. Você pode resolver atribuindo `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"` na chamada do construtor do PDO.

Answer (score 1):

Abra o arquivo no Notepad++ e mude seu *encoding* (codificação): `Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8` ou `Codificação -> Converter para UTF-8`. Caso não quiser (ou não puder) baixar o Notepad++, isso deve ser feito na sua IDE.