# Problema com include causando espaço indesejado

Tags: php, include

Estou criando uma página com algumas includes (*topo* e *footer*) e onde eu coloque esses *includes* aparece um espaço enorme com um código estranho (`&#65279;`) (o código não aparece na página, apenas no inspecionador de elementos do navegador):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vejam na imagem acima o que aparece entre o `<main>` e o `<footer>`, por exemplo. A mesma coisa acontece em todos os lugares onde coloco o include.

Estou fazendo desta forma:

```
<body>
<?php
include 'aa_topo.php';
?>
<main>
   <!-- conteúdo HTML -->   
</main>
<?php
include 'aa_footer.php';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

No código-fonte da página está tudo normal, não aparece nada estranho, mas onde tem esses *includes* está criando um espaçamento vertical de uns 50px entre um elemento e outro (entre o `body` e `main` e entre o `main` e o `footer`).

Se eu colocar os códigos dos *includes* direto na página, fica tudo normal.

O que está causando isso e como posso resolver?

Estou usando um servidor temporário com PHP 5.2.17 e o DreamWeaver CC 2015.

Comment: mostre o aa_footer.php também

Comment: cara tem uma pergunta parecida aqui já https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92639/65279-aparece-esse-erro-entre-o-body-e-d%C3%A1-diferen%C3%A7a-de-espa%C3%A7o

Comment: O Tio sam, voce deve ter copiado algum codigo em  unicode e colado na sua página.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo vovô, não. Criei no Dreamweaver mesmo

Comment: Rapaz não tem nada de BOM nesse treco, só RUIM mesmo kkkk

Comment: Isso já aconteceu comigo varias vezes, colava diretamente no FrontPage e aparecia esses trecos estranhos

Comment: +1 pela piada. Baixa o notepad++, vá em formatação e selecione (UTF8  SEM BOM)

Comment: @VME, é assim que faço quando me defronto com o problema.

Answer (score 6):

O problema que você mencionou é resultado de dois caracteres especiais usados em UTF para indicar a ordem dos bytes.

São chamados de *Byte Order Mark* (BOM). Em hexadecimal, são a sequência 0xFEFF ou 0xFFFE, dependendo da *endianness* do arquivo.

Em UTF-16 o BOM é necessário para determinar a ordem dos bytes, mas em UTF-8 seu uso não é recomendado (e nem faz sentido, por se tratar de um formato sequencial)

Para saber mais sobre o [BOM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHnlt9PqY2U):

> [Para que serve assinatura unicode (BOM)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9940/70)

**Solução especifica para o DreamWeaver:**

Para desativar essa inclusão em arquivos UTF-8 no editor mencionado, desative este checkbox (ou equivalente, na versão que estiver usando):

[image: Screenshot da página de configuração do editor]

Descrição em português, na página da Adobe:

> [Configurar propriedades de codificação e título de uma página](https://helpx.adobe.com/br/dreamweaver/using/set-title-encoding-properties-page.html)