# Obtendo String via Delphi e PHP

Tags: php, delphi

Senhores, boa noite!
Estou com um problema há 3 dias sem conseguir uma solução.

O código abaixo, eu utilizo para obter uma string como forma de autenticação. A variável **sPOST** apresenta a string "*Autorizado*" no evento **ShowMessage**, mas se eu utilizar "*if sPOST = 'Autorizado' then*" ele não funciona.

```
procedure TForm1.btnAuthClick(Sender: TObject);
var                                                                
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;                                                  
  sPOST: String;
  parameters: TStringList;
begin
  parameters := TStringList.Create;
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    parameters.Add('email='+edtUsuario.Text);
    parameters.Add('senha='+Encode64(edtSenha.Text));

    lHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

    //fbURL é uma CONST onde está definido a URL
    sPOST := lHTTP.Post(fbURL+'/lib/consult.php', parameters);
    ShowMessage(sPOST); //Aqui o sPOST recebe a string "Autorizado" ou "Negado".
                        //Está funcionando perfeitamente. A mensagem é exibida com a string correta.

    //Mas aqui, sPOST não parece ter recebido a string,
    //Pois não acata a condição. 
    if sPOST = 'Autorizado' then
      begin
        tbCtrl.ActiveTab:= tabPrincipal; //Abre aba principal
        ShowMessage(sPOST); //Deveria exibir mensagem novamente como teste
      end
    else
      begin ShowMessage('Se lascou!'); end;

  finally
    parameters.Free;
  end;
end;
```

O **consult.php** está assim:

```
$eval = $_REQUEST["email"]; //Aqui já foi utilizado como $_POST, 
$sval = $_REQUEST["senha"]; //mas de nada adiantou.

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbusuario WHERE email='$eval' AND senha='$sval'";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "Autorizado";
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "Negado";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERRO: Não foi possível executar $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Sei que parece um problema meio tosco, mas estou penando com isso. Pois esse IF não funciona nem por um decreto.

Desde já agradeço a atenção e o tempo dedicado de todos.

Comment: E qual o erro ou mensagem aparece do resultado no php?

Comment: Você esta recebendo `"Autorizado"` ou `Autorizado` ?

Comment: Bom dia Caio.  Eu trabalhei um pouco com php e tive alguns problemas de retorno também. Em uma das vezes que estava fazendo esse tipo de comparação que tu quer "if sPOST = 'Autorizado' then" simplismente o caraio da variavel tinha um espaço na frente que o php colocava.  Visualmente no SHOWMESSAGE você realmente nem irá ver que existe esse espaço.. mas acredite.. ele pode estar lá :) . Neste momento é a única coisa que posso pensar :). Abraços.

Comment: Daniel Omine, não recebo mensagem de erro. No ShowMessage antes do IF, a variável sPOST recebe a string "Autorizado", mas no IF ela parece não identificar a string.

Comment: Junior Moreira, ele retorna Autorizado mesmo, sem aspas.

Comment: Ricardo M. Souza, bom dia! Eu cheguei a pensar nisso também, mas não imaginei que fosse um fato, não queria acreditar. Eu vou usar o "trim" ou um StringReplace pra constatar. 
Obrigado mesmo, pela informação. De fato pode ser isso. Abraços.

Comment: Obrigado à todos. Hoje vou fazer mais algumas tentativas e dou uma posição a vocês.

Comment: Ricardo M. Souza, você tinha razão. O safado está imprimindo assim "<body>&#65279;Autorizado</body>". Busquei por essa sequencia e constatei que de fato é um espaço (ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE).
O pior é que nem "Trim", nem "TrimLeft", nem mesmo o StringReplace está conseguindo sanar o problema.
Parece que vou ter que eliminar esse espaço, antes de imprimir o retorno (ECHO).
Achando uma solução, eu informo aqui. Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: Opa! Obrigado, @Rodrigo Rigo, mas eu já tinha tentado o **Trim** também sem solução.
Agora consegui sanar o problema por um outro tópico. O pessoal chama esse erro de **BOM** no PHP.
Segue o link abaixo, caso alguém se depare com o mesmo problema.
[assinatura unicode (BOM)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92639/65279-aparece-esse-erro-entre-o-body-e-d%C3%A1-diferen%C3%A7a-de-espa%C3%A7o)

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde tenta o seguinte:

```
if POS('Autorizado', sPOST) > 0 then
begin
  tbCtrl.ActiveTab:= tabPrincipal; //Abre aba principal
  ShowMessage(sPOST);
end;
```