# Conteúdo da tag <head> fica no <body> quando testo o site

Tags: php, html

@EDIT
SOLUÇÃO == [&#65279 - Aparece esse erro entre o <body> , e dá diferença de espaço](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92639/65279-aparece-esse-erro-entre-o-body-e-d%C3%A1-diferen%C3%A7a-de-espa%C3%A7o)

Tenho esse código:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>assets/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    [...]
  </head>
```

Coloquei o código para carregar o favicon dentro do `<head>`, porém, quando eu inspeciono meu site no chrome, percebi que o conteudo do head fica no `<body>` por algum motivo, e o `<head>` fica vazio e dessa forma o favicon não funciona

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse arquivo é um `.php`

Comment: Seria bom por o referido php no post. De repente tem algo sendo incluido ANTES desse seu código, como um head anterior (nesse caso o browser vai limpar o DOM e manter só o que consegue entender); Compare com o "visualizar código fonte", e não apenas o inspetor.

Comment: @Bacco na verdade os arquivos são .php mas o código é todo html/css/js

Comment: @OtavioSouzaRocha justamente, se vc usa um `<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>` não tem como ser "todo HTML", no minimo tem alguma coisa sendo incluida. Veja a indicação do colega @Sam se resolve, e procure [edit] seu post para por mais detalhes, aí facilita uma solução.

Comment: Talvez isso possa te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92639/65279-aparece-esse-erro-entre-o-body-e-d%C3%A1-diferen%C3%A7a-de-espa%C3%A7o eu já tive o mesmo problema e resolvi dessa forma

Comment: @Sr.AndréBaill funcionou certinho!!!!